# PHP: substr and str_replace don't work as usual

Tags: php, string, url

I juz get the query string from GET parameters as follows:

```
$queryStr= http_build_query($_GET);
```

I tried to apply both str_replace & substr on this string **to replace a certain original value of a get parameter with a desired one.**
Both return the original string with nothing changed.

eg. `$sth = substr($queryStr, 0, 9);`

or 
`$sth = str_replace ("user", "somethingelse",$queryStr);`

What's wrong with this?

**EDITED:**
Ok, sorry. The string function **did't work due to my careless mistake** on a variable in a if condition. They should work fine.

Btw,
I discovered another bug in the function http_build_query() after I change a value of a parameter of $_GET by `$_GET["key"] = "sth";`

Other get parameters that is **array I haven't even touched** have been **automatically changed from "arrayName%5B%5D" to "arrayName%5B0%5D"** in the new query generated by http_build_query()

```
$original_url = http_build_query($_GET);

$_GET["key"] = "sth";

$new_url = http_build_query($_GET);
```

> **original query got from http_build_query():**
>
> &arrayName%5B%5D=
>
> **new query got from http_build_query():**
>
> &arrayName%5B**0**%5D=

**What is the reason for this?**

Comment: We don't see how you use `str_replace`/`substr`. Please add related code.

Comment: Manual: "http_build_query — Generate URL-encoded query string", why are you passing $_GET here?  Access a query param like: $_GET['foo'].

Comment: coz I would like to keep all the get parameters in my url

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code, check value of `$queryStr`

Comment: @u_mulder edited

Comment: What does this question have to do with `regex`?

Comment: coz regex could be the solution to this

Comment: Everything works as expected https://3v4l.org/8i1sH

Comment: _"coz regex could be the solution to thsi "_ - In what way? Only add tags that are directly related to your issue. Don't add tags just because "it _could_ be a solution"

Comment: coz my goal  is  to replace a certain original value of a get parameter with a desired one

Comment: `$_GET['something'] = 'something else'`. Done. No regex.

Comment: I did that and use http_build_query($_GET) again. It gave me the previous query.

Comment: Please show us the full code you tried, together with a dump of the `$_GET`-variable, expected output and what output you're currently getting. Is it the _key_ or the _value_ you're trying to change?

Comment: @Anndexi9 think you should add your URL and expected output, It make easy for us.

Comment: coz I need to generate a url with one parameter different from previous one

Comment: @MagnusEriksson OK. I remove the tag.

Comment: Please, __do not__ describe the code. Post the code and post output of the code that you expect and that is __now__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link provided https://3v4l.org/8i1sH your code works fine:

```
$_GET = ['user' => 'Bob', 'location' => 'city'];
$queryStr = http_build_query($_GET);
echo $queryStr, PHP_EOL;

$sth = str_replace ("user", "somethingelse",$queryStr);
echo $sth, PHP_EOL;
$sth = substr($queryStr, 0, 9);
echo $sth, PHP_EOL;
```

But simpler solution is to replace what you need in `$_GET` array and then build query string, example here https://3v4l.org/i6eKv:

```
// remove items, 
unset($_GET['key']);

// add/replace items
$_GET['another_key'] = 'value';

// and only then
$queryStr = http_build_query($_GET);
```

Comment: If the OP just wants to change the key, it should probably be: `$_GET['another_key'] = $_GET['key'];` instead (and should go before `unset()`.

Comment: That's just an example.

Comment: I understand, but I'm not sure the OP will ;-). Well, since the OP haven't even answered if it's only is the key that should be changed, who knows...

Comment: it is the value of a parameter not key.

Answer (score 2):

Please check, str_replace is working:

Link:
http://localhost/test.php?val1=1&val2=2

$queryStr= http_build_query($_GET);

```
echo "Before " .$queryStr;
$queryStr = str_replace("val1","val2",$queryStr);
echo "<br> After " .$queryStr;

**Output**

Before val1=1&val2=2
After val2=1&val2=2
```

Comment: Link to localhost?

Comment: The link is just for example, it can be anything, Output is already there my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd replace the parameters before you build your query string.

```
<?php
$params = 
[
    'song'   => 'Bridge over troubled water',
    'artist' => 'Simon & Garfunkel',
    'tags'   => 'gorgeous;harmony;bridge'
];
$overrides =
[
    'tags'   => 'dirge;tears',
    'artist' => 'Elvis Presley'
];

$params = array_replace($params, $overrides);

$query_string = http_build_query($params);

var_dump($query_string);
```

Output:

```
string(71) "song=Bridge+over+troubled+water&artist=Elvis+Presley&tags=dirge%3Btears"
```